# Is there an event called when a column is moved in a JTable?

Tags: events, jtable, listener

I have a `JTable` with several columns and rows. Once the user has moved the column, I would like to be informed via an event of some sort, so that I can do some calculations. However, since all I needed to do was

```
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(true);
```

to get the columns to be movable, I am somewhat unsure what I can use to find out once they have been moved.

Any suggestions?

-F

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question..

You need to implement`TableModelListener`, and the `tableChanged` method in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningforColumnRelatedChangesinaJTableComponent.htm) looks at adding a Column Model Listener to a table and detecting when a column is moved. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, the problem there is that I get an event during the moving of my columns. I would like to be informed once the column has been moved (perhaps I could do some combination with a mouse listener and check that the mouse isn't clicked? Dunno..)

-F